# Hash to_json: how can I skip the key and list only the values in the JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rails-activerecord

The result of an `ActiveRecord` query is an array of hashes. If I simply convert this to JSON output, the keys of the hash (the DB column names) will be repeated in the JSON result with every row. E.g. `Dailystats.all.to_json` gives back:

```
[
  {\"statisticsDate\":1360454400000,\"storageTopTempAvg\":48.6},
  {\"statisticsDate\":1360540800000,\"storageTopTempAvg\":49.0},
  {\"statisticsDate\":1360627200000,\"storageTopTempAvg\":48.4}
]
```

However I would like to omit the column names repeated and get only this:

```
[
  {1360454400000:48.6},
  {1360540800000:49.0},
  {1360627200000:48.4}
]
```

Is there a simple way to do this or should I build a data converter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to map the data before you convert it to json:

```
Dailystats.all.map {|item| {item[:statisticsDate] => item[:storageTopTempAvg]}}.to_json
```